# Problem with LINQ Where Clause

Tags: linq

```
var results =  from formNumber in context.DetailTM 
     join c in context.ClaimPeriodTM on formNumber.ClaimPeriod equals c.Cid
     where formNumber.FormNumber.StartsWith(fNumber) 
            && formNumber.RegistrationNumber != registrationNumber
     select new { RegNo = formNumber.RegistrationNumber, 
            CP = c.ClaimPeriod, FormNo = formNumber.FormNumber };
```

The AND CLAUSE with `.StartsWith` Doesn't work. If I use == operator the query works fine.  I tried adding brackets to the where clause but it didn't help.  Any idea what is missing.  Thank you in Advance.

Comment: whats the error notsupportexception?

Comment: and if not an error, what formNumber items are being improperly included or excluded?  we just don't have enough data to help.

Comment: formNumber.RegistrationNumber != registrationNumber
Does not work. i.e
formNumber.RegistrationNumber != 1234

The query is telling not to show 1234 but it still shows

Comment: So you mean its not filtering correctly.

Comment: Yes.  Thats right its not filtering properly. It takes only 1st statement of where clause.  Send one it ignores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something very basic like "&& true == false" and see if that fails.  Also reverse the order.  If you reverse the order, is it still the second clause that fails?

There's nothing about StartsWith that should cause this behavior.  There's something else going on here.  Trim and move elements until you isolate the real bug.

Answer (score 0):

What is the database type for FormNumber? If its char (and not varchar), then you may have to trim one or both sides of the comparison.

```
where
    formNumber.FormNumber.Trim().StartsWith(fNumber.Trim()) 
    && formNumber.RegistrationNumber != registrationNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as jrummells answer, just targetted by the additional comments.

> formNumber.RegistrationNumber != registrationNumber

Check the database types here.  If they are fixed length (char or nchar), you may need to do some trimming.